# Spring Boot cannot find spring-boot-starter-dao-jpa package using Gradle?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have the following Gradle file:

I had this working fine, but all of the sudden it seems like this JPA package cannot be found. I have added it     `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-dao-jpa")`

Every time I try and build, it complains about this. I check the dependency graph and it has a red underline to show it's missing. What can I do?

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.remindful'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket')
    compile('org.springframework.session:spring-session-core')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-dao-jpa")
    compile("com.h2database:h2:1.4.191")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '11.0.2'
    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.197'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.0.1.RELEASE'
}

// To force debug on application boot, switch suspend to y
bootRun {
    systemProperties System.properties
    jvmArgs=["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"]
}
```

Comment: Did you try to clean your project and rebuilt it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no sign of `spring-boot-starter-dao-jpa` in the [Spring Maven Repository](https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/boot/), so I suspect it doesn't exist. Try removing the line.

Maybe this was a copy & paste error from the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency two lines below...?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when I refactored my project structure, intellij got clever and renamed the dependencies. Be careful on that one!